# MS-DOS command/file manager to show file size in MB instead of bytes

Tags: file-management, dos, file

The DIR command, and many MS-DOS file managers I've tried show all file sizes in `bytes` only:

[image]

[image]

Even the Windows 3.1 file manager only shows bytes.

I'm looking for something that will show file sizes in `KB` and `MB`, so it's easier to read. Anyone know a tool?

Comment: You might want to see if the people in [retrocomputing.se] can help you; I'm not quite sure how they feel about requests for software recommendations for retroenvironments.